# I have a vivando project and when I try to create a port map in one of my vhdl programs,I get errors that I don't know how to resolve

Tags: vhdl

I have this vhdl file that I am trying to make a port map for in vivando, but I keep getting errors that I don't understand. I'm relatively new to vhdl and would appreciate any assistance in helping me figure out what I need to change.
This is the program with the port map

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
ENTITY DispAlu4 IS
 PORT(
 a: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0); -- Input SW[7..4]: a[3..0]
 b: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0); -- Input SW[3..0]: b[3..0]
 control: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0); -- Input SW[15..14]: control[1..0]
 led15: OUT STD_LOGIC; -- Output LED[15]: overflow
 led17: OUT STD_LOGIC; -- Output LED[17]: zero
 led16: OUT STD_LOGIC; -- Output LED[16]: cOut
 an: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0); -- Output AN[7..0]: '0' enabled
 hex: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 DOWNTO 0) -- Output HEX[6..0]: result[3..0]
 );
END DispAlu4;
ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF DispAlu4 IS
 COMPONENT Alu4
 PORT(
 a, b: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
 control: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
 overflow: OUT STD_LOGIC;
 zero: OUT STD_LOGIC;
 cOut: OUT STD_LOGIC;
 result: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0)
 );
 END COMPONENT;
 COMPONENT Bin2Hex
 PORT(
 bin: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
 hex: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 DOWNTO 0)
 );
 END COMPONENT;
 SIGNAL overflow_sig: STD_LOGIC;
 SIGNAL zero_sig: STD_LOGIC;
 SIGNAL carry_sig: STD_LOGIC;
 SIGNAL result_sig: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
U1: Alu4 PORT MAP (a, b, control_sig => control, overflow_sig, zero_sig, result_sig, carry_sig); #port map that has errors

END behavioral;
```

These are the other programs referenced in it:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
ENTITY Alu4 IS
 GENERIC( CONSTANT N: INTEGER := 4; -- 4 bits ALU
 CONSTANT Z: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 1) := "000" -- 3 Zeros
 );
 PORT(
 a, b: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
 control: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
 overflow: OUT STD_LOGIC;
 zero: OUT STD_LOGIC;
 cOut: OUT STD_LOGIC;
 result: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0)
 );
END Alu4;
ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF Alu4 IS
 COMPONENT Alu1
 PORT(
 a: IN STD_LOGIC;
 b: IN STD_LOGIC;
 cIn: IN STD_LOGIC;
 control: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
 cOut: OUT STD_LOGIC;
 result: OUT STD_LOGIC
 );
 END COMPONENT;

 SIGNAL carry_sig: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N DOWNTO 0); -- carry_sig(N) = MSB cOut
 SIGNAL result_sig: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
process (a, b, control)
BEGIN
case control is
 WHEN "000" =>
 result_sig <= a AND b;
 WHEN "001" =>
 result_sig <= a OR b;
 WHEN "010" =>
 result_sig <= carry_sig;
 WHEN "011" =>
 result_sig <= carry_sig;
 WHEN "100" =>
 result_sig <= NOT a;
 WHEN "101" =>
 result_sig <= a XOR b;
 WHEN "110" =>
 result_sig <= carry_sig;
 WHEN "111" =>
 result_sig <= NOT b;
 WHEN others =>
 NULL;
 END case;
 END process;
END behavioral;
```

2nd program

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

ENTITY Bin2Hex IS 
    PORT(
        bin:  IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);   --4-bit binary inputs
        hex:  OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 DOWNTO 0)    --7-segment hex display  
    );
END Bin2Hex;
ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF Bin2Hex IS 
BEGIN
    WITH bin SELECT
        hex <=  "1000000"   WHEN "0000", --0
          "1111001" when "0001", --1
          "0100100" when "0010", --2
          "0110000" WHEN "0011", --3
          "0011001" WHEN "0100", --4
          "0010010" WHEN "0101", --5
          "0000010" WHEN "0110", --6
          "1111000" WHEN "0111", --7
          "0000000" WHEN "1000", --8
          "0010000" WHEN "1001", --9
          "0001000" WHEN "1010", --A
          "0000011" WHEN "1011", --b
          "0100110" WHEN "1100", --C
          "0100001" WHEN "1101", --d
          "0000110" WHEN "1110", --E
          "0001110" WHEN "1111", --F
          "1111111" when others;        
    
                
END behavioral;
```

Comment: Comments are delimited by "--" and the end of line, not `#` you introduced another error. A port map association list can have associations that are positional or named, associating the formal port with actual expression (here signals).  Once you switch to named association you can't switch back to positional, because named association is unordered. There's no way of knowing during syntactical analysis whether or not the named association is also positional ordered so you get an error. Show the complete error message. Did you mean (Xilinx) Vivado instead of Vivando? (If so add it's tag.)

Comment: You also have the named association going actual => formal instead of formal => actual. You could just use positional association for formal control. Actual control_sig isn't declared. Entity alu be alu4 in the component declaration. There are several other errors.

Comment: Yes I meant xilinx

Comment: The synthesis error message would have been something like `Error [Synth 8-2549] positional association cannot follow named association`.